# Ceramics spots after placement

Tags: adhesive, ceramic-tile

I renovated my apartment this month and hired some guys to place the ceramics in the bathroom. They used points of adhesive to glue pottery on the wall. In the evening I observed that few spots appeared on pottery right where the adhesive is located. It is normal? Will they dry?

[image: some affected tiles]

Comment: I must say that your photo does nothing to communicate anything about the spots except to show that you can draw arrows in a paint program.

Comment: This might just be the coffee talking, but I think I can see blobs. (Which would be an unconventional way to set tiles, to say the least.) What kind of tiles are they? (Information from the box they came in at least.)

Comment: @MichaelKaras I was trying to help users see the spots in the picture.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate. Yeah. They are blobs. The guys told me that the wall is not vertical and they cannot put more material between the tile and the wall. I bought Marazzi Pasta Blanca wall tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few day I saw that the spots are disappearing. I searched for an expert opinion and he told me that the adhesive is working and will dry eventually.

Comment: Happy to hear that's clearing up. For anyone else reading this that's trying to save money on a tile job, I'd suggest that DIY with a bit of reading will produce better results than a poor tradesperson.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Yeah. You are right. The only issue is that DIY requires a bit of practice and I did not have time for that.